# How make a combobox with php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

I trying make a combobox with php and mysql but i cant find a solution. How I can fix this code?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM exemple") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <h1>Combo</h1>
    <select name="cbx" id="cbx">
    <?php while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $ri['exemp'] ?>">
        <?php echo $ri['exemp2'] ?>
      </option>
    </select>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: what is `$result` ?! please post all the code related to your issue.

Comment: Hi, @Kalil Alves, since you are new here, I recommend you reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will get better feedback by following those tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, close `while` loop before `</select>` tag:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <h1>Combo</h1>
  <select name="cbx" id="cbx">
    <?php while ($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ri['exemp'] ?>"><?php echo $ri['exemp2'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</form>
```